# ClamAV - installation and automatic updates on OS version which reached its EOL

Tags: rhel, clamav

My server is running on RHEL 6.7 (its life cycle ended on December 31, 2018)

Now, I want to install ClamAV but I am wondering whether it is legal to install and run ClamAV on an outdated OS without serious issues?

Do ClamAV software/signature updates not relate to OS? And does ClamAV still auto update signature everyday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running an outdated OS which receives no security updates is not really a good idea.

> it is legal to install and run ClamAV on an outdated OS without serious issues?

There's nothing illegal about that and there could be no issues as long as it works.

> Do ClamAV software/signature updates not relate to OS?

ClamAV updates have nothing to do with the underlying OS.

> And does ClamAV still auto update signature everyday?

It's done using a cron job. You can set it up to receive signature updates each hour.